# Generating proper CSV files

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I'm having a problem programmatically generating a proper CSV file that is then downloaded by the user and opened in excel in my ASP.NET project.  Excel seems to open the file properly but when I go to “save as” it defaults to Unicode text.  I understand that CSV is basically a text file but if you try creating a CSV in Excel, saving, and then going to save as it will default the save as type to CSV.  Therefore I believe something extra is being saved along with the file.   I’ve made sure the HTTP header context-type is set to “text/csv” so I am sure that the response is correct to the user.

Comment: Please post the source code you use to generate the file as well as a sample CSV file generated by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generate a lot of CSV where I work, and I've noticed this a lot. There's a really good chance that your file is just fine.

The problem with CSV is that it's not defined by any standard, so every app interprets it slightly different. Excel probably does this for any CSV file which isn't precisely in its preferred format.

Maybe Excel expects CSV to be ASCII, and you've got a UTF BOM in the file which makes it decide tab-delimited "Unicode text" is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks!!  This did work.  Excel needs the file to be ASCII format in order to "Save As" properly as a CSV

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Write("1;computer;1000");
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a binary dump of the file to make sure the file being downloaded is identical to the file you're looking at locally? There could be different line terminators being used (e.g.  ) that might be causing Excel to tolerantly read it in and display it, but default to saving it as unicode text.

On a Linux (or cygwin) system, using "od -a -x" will tell you how the file is made up.